# Speed up checking every cell in a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I need to speed up this macro & to avoid specifying a range as (A2:A2000) for example because my data is dynamic.

My macro checks every cell with the same value in some columns to merge it

```vb
Sub Merge_Duplicated_Cells()
'
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Cell As Range
    
' Merge Duplicated Cells

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Sheets("1").Select
    Set myrange = Range("A2:A2000, B2:B2000, L2:L2000, M2:M2000, N2:N2000, O2:O2000")
    
CheckAgain:
    For Each Cell In myrange
        If Cell.Value = Cell.Offset(1, 0).Value And Not IsEmpty(Cell) Then
            Range(Cell, Cell.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
            Cell.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            GoTo CheckAgain
        End If
    Next

    Sheets("2").Select
    Set myrange = Range("A2:A2000, B2:B2000, L2:L2000, M2:M2000, N2:N2000, O2:O2000")

    For Each Cell In myrange
        If Cell.Value = Cell.Offset(1, 0).Value And Not IsEmpty(Cell) Then
            Range(Cell, Cell.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
            Cell.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            GoTo CheckAgain
        End If
    Next
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    MsgBox "Report is ready"
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix add

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

after your code

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

and

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

after your code

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

and to improve the macro not processing blank ranges,

```
dim ws as worksheet
dim lastrowA, lastrowB, lastrow C as long


'Instead of setting last row to 2000, can use the actual last row by eg:

'find last row of data in column A'
lastrowA = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'find last row of data in column B'
lastrowB = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

'find last row of data in column C'
lastrowC = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
```

and insert these into the macro instead of 2000 eg:

```
Set myrange = Range("A2:A" & lastrowA & ,
```

Comment: Could you check the code after you comments
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrowA, lastrowB, lastrowC As Long
    
Set myrange = Range("A2:A" & lastrowA) 
'' got error Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed ''

'find last row of data in column A'
lastrowA = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Sheets("1").Select
CheckAgain:
    For Each Cell In myrange
        If Cell.Value = Cell.Offset(1, 0).Value And Not IsEmpty(Cell) Then
            Range(Cell, Cell.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
            Cell.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            GoTo CheckAgain
        End If
Next

Answer (score 0):

The slowdown in your code is primarily due to the presence of the `GoTo CheckAgain` transition, due to which the cycle of processing the same cells is repeated many times. In addition, multiple calls to the cells of the sheet are used, which is very time consuming. In the code below, unnecessary cycles are excluded, reading data from the sheet, merging and formatting cells are performed immediately for the entire processed subrange.

I ran the code on 2 sheets with 10000 rows each, it took 2.6 sec.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test1()
    'Here we indicate only the starting cells in each column, because
    'the size of the non-empty area in these columns is calculated
    'automatically in the MergeCells() procedure
    MergeCells Sheets("1").Range("A2,B2,L2,M2,N2,O2")
    MergeCells Sheets("2").Range("A2,B2,L2,M2,N2,O2")
End Sub

Sub MergeCells(myrange As Range)
    Dim v As Variant, col As Range, Cell As Range, toMerge(0 To 1) As Range, k As Long, index As Byte, area As Variant, arr As Variant, skip As Boolean
    
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
        For Each col In myrange
            ' next line reads all the data from sheet's column at once
            arr = col.Resize(myrange.Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, col.Column).End(xlUp).Row - col.Row + 1)
            
            For k = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1) - 1 'loop through all rows of an array
                If Not skip And arr(k, 1) = arr(k + 1, 1) And Not IsEmpty(arr(k, 1)) Then
                    'to prevent "gluing" adjacent sub-ranges within the same range,
                    'two ranges are used in the toMerge array, all odd sub-ranges are collected
                    'in the element with index 0, all even ranges are collected in the element
                    'with index 1, and Index switches from 0 to 1 and vice versa after each array subrange
                    If toMerge(index) Is Nothing Then
                        Set toMerge(index) = col.Offset(k - col.Row + 1).Resize(2)
                    Else
                        Set toMerge(index) = Union(col.Offset(k - col.Row + 1).Resize(2), toMerge(index))
                    End If
                    index = 1 - index
                    skip = True ' if merged, skip next cell
                Else
                    skip = False
                End If
            Next
            ' if the ranges for merge are non-empty, we merge and format simultaneously for all subranges
            For Each area In toMerge
                If Not area Is Nothing Then
                    area.Merge
                    area.VerticalAlignment = XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter
                End If
            Next
            Set toMerge(0) = Nothing
            Set toMerge(1) = Nothing
        Next
        
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your effort "Its worked nice"  - my point to merge Columns (A2 - B2 - L2 - M2 - N2 - O2) merge cells for each col individually not merge columns with each other

Comment: perfect update from you .. I need check consecutive same cells as value & merge it  as below

         Col A ColB      ColC
Row1 Home Test      Home
Row2
Row3
Row4 Test         Test      Test
Row5
Row6
Row7 Home Home Home
Row8 Test         Test         Test
Row9
Row10
Row11
Row12
Row13 Home Home Home

Sorry i can't attached file to explain it exactly

Comment: and another point >> Merge start for Col A from A2 while rest of Columns start from B3  ... L3 ... etc

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly .... besides the already existing answer, another way (which is not meant to be better) maybe something like this :

Before and after running the sub (please ignore the yellow fill and the border, as it is used just to be easier to see the result) like image below :

[image] ===> [image]

```
Sub test()
Dim LR As Integer: Dim cnt As Integer
Dim i  As Integer: Dim c As Range

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    LR = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
    cnt = .Columns.Count
End With

For i = 1 To cnt
    Set c = Cells(1, i)
        Do
        If c.Value <> "" And c.Value = c.Offset(1, 0).Value _
            Then Range(c, c.Offset(1, 0)).Merge _
                Else Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop Until c.Row > LR
Next

End Sub
```

LR is the last row of the used range of the active sheet.
cnt is the column count of the used range of the active sheet.

Then it loop from 1 to as many as the cnt as i variable.
Inside this loop, it create the starting cell as c variable, then do the inner loop, by checking each c within the looped column (the i in cnt) if the row below c has the same value then it merge this c and the c.offset(1,0). The inner loop stop when the c.row is larger than the LR, then it goes to the next i (the next column).

Please note, the data should start from column A ... because the outer loop assume that the column to be in the inner loop will start from column 1 (column A). And also, the code doesn't do any fancy things, such as alignment, font size, border, etc.